# Whats the difference between current_page_item and current-menu-item

Tags: menus

Whats the difference between `current_page_item` and `current-menu-item` when using Custom Menus

```
.current_page_item{} // Class for Current Page
.current-cat{} // Class for Current Category
.current-menu-item{} // Class for any other current Menu Item
.menu-item-type-taxonomy{} // Class for a Category
.menu-item-type-post_type{} // Class for Pages
.menu-item-type-custom{} // Class for any custom item that you added
.menu-item-home{} // Class for the Home Link
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

current_menu_item is the active element in the menu, independent from the type (page, archives, post, etc.) of the current menu element, while current_page_item only available, if the current item is a page and is current.

For more details: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/#menu-item-css-classes

Comment: [`current_page_item` is added for backwards compatibility](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php#L351) for themes that only support the older `wp_page_menu()` menus, which only had pages in them. So if you are creating a theme now it's best to use `current-menu-item`.