# Add custom attribute to menu item link using Filter

Tags: menus, accessibility

In order to increase my theme's accessibility, I want to add the `aria-current="page"` attribute to the menu item that has the class `.current_page_item`.

As of right now, I am doing this via jQuery using the following:

```
var currentitem = $( '.current_page_item > a' );
currentitem.attr( 'aria-current', 'page' );
```

While this does what I want it to do, I would prefer that PHP handles this particular thing.

I know I can do this either with a custom Nav Walker class or with a filter to `nav_menu_link_attributes`. Unfortunately I have not seen any code even remotely near what I want to do.

```
function my_menu_filter( $atts, $item, $args, $depth ) {
   // Select the li.current_page_item element
   // Add `aria-current="page"` to child a element
}
add_filet( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'my_menu_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Any help in writing this filter would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the examples given here? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes

Comment: I looked at those but didn't see how to get at the classes. Normally I do a `var_dump` or `print_r` of the object and look for what I want to target in there but I couldn't get that in this case and the only example I found to do that did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may target the `current_page_item` CSS class or you may target the `current-menu-item` CSS class instead. `current_page_item` class may not be present for all kinds of menu item. Read [the answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14978/whats-the-difference-between-current-page-item-and-current-menu-item) to know why.

Whichever CSS class you choose, you may use the CODE like the following to set the attribute:

```
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'wpse260933_menu_atts_filter', 10, 3 );
function wpse260933_menu_atts_filter( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    if( in_array( 'current-menu-item', $item->classes ) ) {
        $atts['aria-current'] = 'page';
    }
    return $atts;
}
```

Comment: I tried this code and it didn't work. I double checked the `li` element and it only had the `current_page_item` class. I changed your conditional to that class and it still did not work. I even tried to have it switch the `href` attribute to `#` as a test and nothing happened.

Comment: Also, don't forget, as the `nav_menu_link_attributes` name suggests, this `aria-current="page"` attribute will be added within the menu link (i.e. within  `<a href="_link_" aria-current="page">Menu</a>`). Not in `li` element. Also, an older WP installation may only have `current_page_item` class.

Comment: WP v4.7.3 and it was both in a file being called by `functions.php` and I tried it in `functions.php` itself. And I do want it to affect the `<a>` element within. The only reason the `<li>` element comes into play is it is the one getting the class I am using to target.

Comment: I copied the code onto a fresh copy of WordPress on a different local server and still had the same results. Is there something I need to enable in `wp-config.php` or elsewhere? I've messed with priority settings, even changed the filter to replace the `href` with `#` and nothing happens.

Comment: Is there a way to see if this is even loading?

Comment: Enable Debugging in `wp-config.php`: `define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);` then check `debug.log` file in `/wp-content/` directory. Use the code `error_log( __FUNCTION__);` within the filter function to see if it's loading. Also, log other parameters similarly in that function if needed.

Comment: I found the issue, which also explained why the `current-menu-item` was missing as well. The menu got unassigned and the fallback one is identical to the one I use for testing. Once I assigned it, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter `nav_menu_link_attributes` to achieve that:

```
function add_attribute_to_current_menu_item( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    // check if this item represents the current post
    if ( $item->object_id  == get_the_ID() ) 
    {
        // add the desired attributes:
        $atts['aria-current'] = 'page';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_attribute_to_current_menu_item', 10, 3 );
```

See [nav_menu_link_attributes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/nav_menu_link_attributes) for more information.

Comment: +1 but you will probably want to make sure the item is a post/page/etc to make sure the item->object_id is actually something you can compare to the post id

Comment: This check: `$item->object_id  == get_the_ID()` may not work always.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work